# What is more accurate for this situation, Timer or CountDownTimer

Tags: android, timer

I am developing a game that is changing its state every 1-5 seconds. I am not sure whether to use the **Timer** or the **CountDownTimer** class.

I am looking mainly for accuracy, which one is more precise?

Comment: I don´t think it makes a difference. The only advantage of a timer is, You don´t need start it again and again. A countdown timer must be started again after countodwn is reached.

Comment: @Clay Do u need to stop in between if u set state for 5 seconds?If yes then don't use CountdownTimer use Timer.

Comment: @Indiandroid I don't need to stop but I need the next iteration of the timer to have a different time period.

Comment: Also continuous delayed timers in using Runnable u can use @Clay Check this blog http://custardbelly.com/blog/blog-posts/2010/10/01/timers-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind scenario, I must suggest you to use Timer class, because once it started you dont need to start and start it again, once it starts it will going on its way as per your seconds or minutes gap given to it.

In countdown timer , you must need to restart it when it reaches to its end point.

So as per my suggestion, Timer is best in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If your 1 to 5 seconds is a fixed period of time then Timer is a more appropriate fit. Simple usage of each will provide equal accuracy. If your "change state" process is time/processor intensive then the accuracy between fixed periods can suffer and lead you to a more involved multi-threaded solution.